# Visual Studio 2017 V15.9.4 - CSharpRenameTrackingCodeFixProvider encountered an error and has been disabled

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

While renaming the class name in Visual Studio 2017 V15.9.4. It is showing issue at top of editor as CSharpRenameTrackingCodeFixProvider encountered an error and has been disabled

Stack trace for error as below

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. ---> Unable to check out the files from source control.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Suggestions.SuggestedAction.InvokeWorker(Func`1 getFromDocument,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Suggestions.SuggestedAction.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<InvokeCore>b__0()
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Extensions.IExtensionManagerExtensions.PerformAction(IExtensionManager extensionManager,Object extension,Action action)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception : Unable to check out the files from source control.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioWorkspaceImpl.EnsureEditableDocuments(IEnumerable`1 documents)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioWorkspaceImpl.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution,IProgressTracker progressTracker)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.RenameTracking.RenameTrackingTaggerProvider.RenameTrackingCommitter.UpdateWorkspaceForGlobalIdentifierRename(Workspace workspace,Solution newSolution,Solution oldSolution,String undoName,IEnumerable`1 changedDocuments,ISymbol symbol,String newName,Int32 trackingSessionId)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.RenameTracking.RenameTrackingTaggerProvider.RenameTrackingCommitter.ApplyChangesToWorkspace(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.RenameTracking.RenameTrackingTaggerProvider.RenameTrackingCommitter.Commit(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.RenameTracking.RenameTrackingTaggerProvider.RenameTrackingCodeAction.RenameTrackingCommitterOperation.Apply(Workspace workspace,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeActions.CodeActionOperation.TryApply(Workspace workspace,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.CodeActions.CodeActionEditHandlerService.ProcessOperations(Workspace workspace,ImmutableArray`1 operations,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.CodeActions.CodeActionEditHandlerService.ApplyAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)<---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to remove the read only attribute of all the folders of solution in order to resolve this.